# Is there a way to apply reduce to two arrays but not reset the accumulator between calls?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

So if I have an array of objects:

```
var synched = [{
   name = "something",
   value = 11132
}, {
   name = "something else",
   value = 1231233
}...]
```

and another array that is pretty much the same but holds some other values:

```
var opened = [{
   name = "something",
   value = 1233312
}, {
   name = "something else",
   value = 12312333
}, {
   name = "something",
   value = 1241233
```

}]

I wanted to join them all up into a single array of objects where I count the total of accurances of "name" in either array.

```
var result = [{
    name: "something",
    opened: 2,
    synched: 1,
    total: 3
}, {
    name: "something else",
    opened: 1,
    synched: 1,
    total: 2
}]
```

Is there a more efficient way to do that than multiple `array.reduce` calls?

```
var data = synched.reduce(function (data, item) {
    var key = item.name
    var created = (data[key] || (data[key] = {'name': key, 'opened': 0, 'synched': 0, 'total': 0}));
    created['synched'] += 1;
    created['total'] += 1;

    return data;
}, {});

var data1 = opened.reduce(function (data1, item) {
    var key = item.name
    var created = (data1[key] || (data1[key] = {'name': key, 'opened': 0, 'synched': 0, 'total': 0}));
    created['opened'] += 1;
    created['total'] += 1;

    return data1;
}, {});

Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
    if(data1.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        data1[key]['synched'] = data[key]['synched'];
        data1[key]['total'] = data[key]['total'] + data1[key]['total'];
    } else {
        data1[key] = data[key];
    }
});

var result = Object.keys(data1).map(function(item) { return data1[item]; });
```

EDIT:

Following @Pointy suggestion i can do this:

```
var data1 = opened.reduce(function (data, item) {
        var key = item.name
        var created = (data[key] || (data[key] = {'name': key, 'opened': 0, 'synched': 0, 'total': 0}));
        created['opened'] += 1;
        created['total'] += 1;

        return data;
    }, data);
```

and that will allow me to get rid of that third iteration. Thanks!

Comment: Just pass `data` to the second `.reduce()`?

Comment: As an accumulator argument?

Comment: Ahhh! Got it! It's the initial value. I need to pass `data` in as an accumulator but also as the initial value instead of `{}`. That's why it was just resetting my data output. I see now. Thanks!